# rename menu based on role in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How does one rename a menu (or page name) based on roles in wordpress? I added 2 roles in my wordpress site [teacher, student] and several menu names [home, activity, corner, contact us]. The menu names are static pages pages created in page templates file; the menu is created by 
appearance->menu. When a teacher is logged into site the corner menu should be renamed 'teachers corner'. When a student is logged into the site the corner menu should be renamed 'students corner'. How to do that? If you have an idea how to do this things, please share your idea. I used "Nav Menu Roles" plugin but there is no option for to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the adding new user or the wordpress plugin role editor